# Perturbation of eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a singular symmetric positive semi-definite matrix and let $\delta A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix with $\mathcal O(\delta)$ entries such that $A + \delta A$ is invertible. Let $\lambda > 0$ and let $(\lambda, v)$ be a eigenpair for $A$, i.e., $Av = \lambda v$. I am interested in solving for $x \in \mathbb R^n$ the linear system
$$
(A+\delta A)\, x = \lambda(v+\delta v),
$$
where $\delta v \in \mathbb R^n$ is a vector with $\mathcal O(\delta)$ entries. In the limit $\delta \to 0$, the linear system reduces to $Ax = \lambda v$, and therefore
$$
x = v + w,  \quad  \forall w \in\mathrm{Ker}(A).
$$
Experimentally, I noticed that for $\delta > 0$ the unique solution $x$ is as well of the form $x = v+w$, with the norm of $w$ being small.

Is there any result in literature which allow to bound the norm of such a vector $w$?

**Edit:**

Let $x = v + w$. Then, replacing $x$ in the perturbed system as
$$
(A+\delta A) \, (v + w) = \lambda (v + \delta v),
$$
and exploiting that $Av = \lambda v$, yields
$$
(A+\delta A) w = \lambda \delta v - \delta A v.
$$
Can we deduce something from this?

Comment: Are $A$ and $\delta A$ supposed to be symmetric?

Comment: I would think that taking the least-squares solution to $Ax = \lambda(v + \epsilon v)$ would make the norm of $w$ sufficiently small.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $A$ is symmetric, I edited the question, while $\delta A$ is not (just invertible). For your second comment: I'm interested in the solution of the perturbed system, so on the left-hand side we have $A + \delta A$.

Comment: Do you mean $\epsilon\,v$ or $\epsilon_v$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just named the vector "$\epsilon v$", like I named the matrix $\delta A$: it's just a vector with small entries. If you prefer, you can think of it as of $\delta v$. I just didn't want to suggest that $\delta A$ and $\delta v$ go to zero (entry-wise) with the same speed w.r.t. $\delta$.

Comment: Why not $\delta v$ then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust But probably you're right, a better name is $\delta v$. I modify the question.

Comment: Presumably you had something in mind like "$\delta$ for input perturbations, $\epsilon$ for output perturbations," as in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. Either works though

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well, not really, I just chose the two symbols that in math are most used to denote "smallness"

Comment: @G.Gare Ah, in any case I guess it all makes sense.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've edited my question, in case this problem interests you, or you have ideas.

Comment: I think what you are really doing here is effectively perturbing a linear system only. Namely if $b=\lambda v$ then you know $Av=b$ and now you perturb the matrix and the RHS and ask what happens to the solution. The issue is that since $A$ is singular, the details depend on the relationship between the perturbation of the coefficient matrix and the perturbation of the RHS.

Comment: ...and the extreme case of that dependence is exactly what Omnomnomnom showed, where $\delta v$ is orthogonal to the range of $A$ and so $w$ has a component which scales like $\| \delta v \|/\| \delta A \|$.

Comment: @Ian very cool, I'm trying to understand it 100% but your hints are definitely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are trying to estimate
$$
w = (A + \delta A)^{-1}(\lambda \delta v - \delta Av).
$$
Unless we are given that $\delta v$ is taken from the image of $A$, we have no reason to believe that $w$ will be small. For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad v = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad \lambda = 1, \quad \delta v = \delta_1 \pmatrix{0\\1}, \quad \delta A = \delta_2 I.
$$
We find that
$$
w = \pmatrix{1 + \delta_2&0\\0&\delta_2}^{-1} \pmatrix{-\delta_2\\ \delta_1} = \pmatrix{\frac{-\delta_2}{1+\delta_2}\\ \frac{\delta_1}{\delta_2}}.
$$
The first entry will indeed be small for small values of $\delta_2$, but we have no way to bound the second entry.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is indeed very helpful to have a "counterexample". Imagining that $\delta_1 = \delta_2^2$, for example (perturbations on the r.h.s. go faster to zero than those on the l.h.s.), would make $w$ small, am I correct?

Comment: @G.Gare Correct. However, I'm not sure that you can predict how much "faster" we must have $\delta v \to 0$

Comment: @G.Gare Actually, it might be useful to consider
$$
w = (A + \delta A)^{-1}(\lambda \delta v - \delta Av) = 
(A(\delta A)^{-1} + I)^{-1}(\lambda (\delta A)^{-1} \delta v - v)
$$

Comment: Oh, yes, of course! The norm of $(I+A(\delta A)^{-1})^{-1}$ should be easy to bound, but for the difference.. It's unclear whether Cauchy-Schwarz is applicable with success. Why should $\lambda (\delta A)^{-1} \delta v$ be close to $v$ in any sense

Comment: @G.Gare If you know that $\|\delta v\| \approx \|(\delta A)^{-1}\|^{-2}$, however, then you could make this term close to zero.